# Allow multiple users to login at the same time in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a django project and I have completed working on it. And I tested it and ran the project in on two webpages in chrome with my localhost:8000 server . I logged in in first page as a first user , lets say user1  and logged in on another page with another username , lets say user2 . But when I refresh the first page , the user1 is not logged in and I get logged in as the user2. The first page user1 is not logged  in . I want to login multiple users at the same time so I can interact with the page. Kindly help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs in, django stores information on the browser, which is why this happens.  What you can do is open up a private window [private window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and have the second user log in there.  You can also use another browser to test out a third user.  There might be a more efficient method, but this is quick an d simple solution.

**UPDATE**

After a bit of checking I found a much better solution to the question.  [Ghost Browser](https://ghostbrowser.com/) was made for this specific situation.  And since as of now this does not work in Linux, you can also use extensions in Firefox, like [Temporary Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/), and there probably are similar extensions for other browsers.

Comment: Yes, check out my updated answer, and thanks for the question!  I learned something new from it, thanks to you.

Comment: Hello sir . Please can you help me with this problem in django I am facing now . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71020091/internal-server-error-when-deployed-django-project-to-heroku